# AYUDA en Android Studio: "Rendering Problems: One or more layouts are missing the layout_width or layout_height attributes"

Tags: android-studio, android-layout

Estaba viendo un tutorial para hacer un menú lateral, y al momento de hacer el layout de *"navigation_header"* me aparece éste error de renderizado. Estoy siguiendo el tutorial al pie de la letra y no sé por qué ocurrió. Estoy en la versión 2.1.2.

Aquí les dejo la imagen del error y el enlace del vídeo:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A-AI5AbLVqo&index=2&list=PLGCjwl1RrtcR1j6EmpBxJyJYowK2QIsdT

Seguí los pasos del tutorial de cómo crearlo; es decir, *layout>New>Layout resource file*, nombré mi *layout* y en *Root element* le puse *RelativeLayout*, y en el tutorial funcionó pero a mí no.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En las propiedades traté de modificarlos pero al hacerlo, es como si se borrara la propiedad, pero en *text* me aparece así, y ese es todo el código del *layout*:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

PD: ya intenté cambiar el *API* y el tema de Android y me sigue dando problemas, algunos con menos errores y otros con más.

Comment: Agrega tu layout por favor.

Comment: Agrega todo el código de tu layout.

Comment: Ya, pero eso es todo lo que me sale.

Comment: Ese layout esta incompleto e incorrecto. Prueba a esitarlo manualmente a ver si sigue saliendo el error. Echa un ojo a este enlace de la [guía oficial de Android para desarrolladores](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout?hl=es-419)

Comment: @DevCodeG es que seguí los pasos del tutorial de cómo crearlo; es decir, *layout>New>Layout resource file*, nombré mi layout y en *Root element* le puse *RelativeLayout*, y en el tutorial funcionó pero a mí no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error te lo indican en la primera imagen, layout_height y layout_width son valores que tienen que indicarse en todos los elementos de un layout.
La segunda imagen dices que es todo el código que tienes en el layout, si ese todo el código que tienes es imposible que funcione. Lo mínimo que tiene que haber en el texto de un layout y que se crea automáticamente al crear uno es esto, aunque con la nueva versión es un constraint_layout, te he puesto el ejemplo del relative_layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</RelativeLayout>
```

Y por cada elemento nuevo que crees tienes que darle las propiedades layout_width y layout_height, si no te dará un error, aquí tienes un ejemplo de un RelativeLayout con un par de elementos:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <EditText android:id="@+id/TxtNombre"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:inputType="text" />

    <Button android:id="@+id/BtnAceptar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/TxtNombre"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias! Cambié el código por el que indicaste y funcionó.